# ASP.Net MVC How to create a one-to-many relationship between the ApplicationUser and my own class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, one-to-many

I am creating a ASP.Net MVC project in Visual Studio Community 2015 where I have to enable users to create and manage advertisements. This is a one-to-many relationship meaning that a user may create as many advertisements as he pleases. Every user can see all advertisements but only the ones that created them can edit them. Since the MVC template already comes with Identity implemented, I want to use the class ApplicationUser as my user class.

I added a class Avertisement to my Model folder that looks like this:

```
 public class Advertisement
{
    public int AdvertisementId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Then I added the Advertisement DbSet to the ApplicationDbContext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) {}

    public DbSet<Advertisement> Advertisements { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Afterwards, I enable migrations and rebuild the solution:

```
Enable-Migrations
add-migrations InitialCreate
update-database
```

Until this point everything runs smoothly. Now comes my problem. I now try scaffolding by adding an Advertisement controller with the "MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework" template but the generated controller comes with the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKj95.png) that appears everytime db.ApplicationUsers appears on the controller. I have no idea what I am doing wrong and I've looked everywhere on stackoverflow and the internet but none of the solutions worked for me. What do you think could be wrong?

[image: 1]

Comment: what is the type of `db` in your controller?

Comment: It is the default that comes with the controller scaffolding: private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

Comment: Sharing the actual error message as text is much more useful than having to click away to a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a good idea, my bad.

Comment: try db.Advertisements.ApplicationUser ?

Comment: @Chandru Autocomplete doesn't even show me the ApplicationUser option after Advertisements, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add the link between `ApplicationUser` and `Advertisment`, find the `ApplicationUser` class and add this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Add this line
    // vvvvvvvvvvvvv
    public virtual ICollection<Advertisment> Advertisments { get; set; }
}
```

In your action method, you access the users with this:

```
db.Users
```

Comment: Thanks, replacing it with db.Users worked! I guess my problem was that I was to trusting in the scaffolding capabilities and the automatic pluralization ruined it. Regarding your first advice, isn't it possible to only have the link in one of the classes in one-to-many relationships?

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationUser` is just a class Identity creates for you. The actual table where Identity stores the user data is `AspNetUsers`, so

```
db.AspNetUsers
```

should work for you.

Comment: It doesn't work. The same error appears but now with AspNetUsers.